# git - develop base and extended feature - commits in base should reflect in extended in pull

Tags: git, github, software-engineering

Hie I am working around in git to achieve something like mentioned below.

Imagine there is a Big feature which is going to develop - since it's very big they have split into core feature and an extended feature.

Now they have divided into teams for development.

Now how to make branches in a below-mentioned way

the core will be developing in core_branch extended will be developing in extended_branch containing core development it should be like that when we perform git pull in extended_branch it has to pull if any commits made to core_branch how to achieve this??

I am aware of git rebase / git merge. In either of the cases, extended team/developers have to check any new commits in the core branch and merge/rebase their extended_branch

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a large project with multiple teams using multiple development branches will give you merge headaches, especially if the core and extended features have a significant overlap in the codebase.

The extended feature team(s) will spend a lot of time periodically merging the core feature changes and dealing with the fallout from each such merge, which can not be properly/realistically estimated ahead of time. If there are multiple teams working on the extended feature they might decide to go on separate branches to further isolate and protect themselves against these periodic merge instabilities. It's just an illusion, that'll make things even worse at the overall project level - it can lead to [Branch Merge Hell](http://www.agilebuddha.com/agile/from-branch-merge-hell-to-trunk-based-development-a-bank-agile-case-study-2-n/).

You may want to take a look at [Trunk-Based Development (TBD)](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/), with [feature-flags](/questions/tagged/feature-flags) and/or [branch by abstraction](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html). Most effective when using a [gated-commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_commit) CI system.